# REST API - PATCH request do not works when a guest user computer accesses the application

Tags: angularjs, rest

I'm using angular $http to send data to update through PATCH verb. When I access the application using **administrator users**, works fine, but for **another users it's not works**!

On Chrome developer tool this request keeps loading forever, and show this request header:

```
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/javascript
Content-Type:application/json
```

See my code example bellow

```
...
    atualizar: function(data) {
        return $http({
            method: 'PATCH', 
            url: frontend.homeUrl + '/api/sinistro/' + data.id, 
            responseType: 'json', 
            data: data, 
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            }
        });
    }
....
```

Anyone help me, please?

**SOLUTION**

For PATCH request, the browser user needs administrator permission. Or needs change request PATCH to POST.

Comment: If the request is loading forever, that sounds like a server side problem, not Angular.

Comment: Thanks fot reply. Yes. Not a angular error. This occurs because the application user don't have a administrator permission of computer. For PATCH request, the browser user needs administrator permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PATCH request, the browser user needs administrator permission. Or needs change request PATCH to POST.